# c++ splitting string on non alphabetic characters

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am reading in a file line by line which I want to split on non alphabetic characters and if possible remove all non alphabetic characters at same time so I wouldn't have to do it latter.

I would like to use `isalpha`, but cant figure out how to use that with str.find() or similar functions, as those usually take single delimiter as a a string.

```
    while(getline(fileToOpen,str))
    {
        unsigned int pos= 0;
        string token;
        //transform(str.begin(),str.end(),str.begin(),::tolower);
        while (pos = str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"))
        {
            token = str.substr(0, pos);
            //transform(str.begin(),str.end(),str.begin(),::tolower);

            Node<t>* ptr=search(token,root);
            if (ptr!=NULL)
            {
                ptr->count++;
                cout<<token<<" already in tree.Count "<<ptr->count<<"\n";
            }
            else
            {
                insert(token,root);
                cout<<token<<" added to tree.\n";
            }
            ptr=NULL;
            str.erase(0, pos);
        }

    }
```

My latest attempt which doesn't work... All of examples I could find were based on `str.find("single delimiter")`

Which is no good to me.

Found a  way to use `isalpha`

```
template<typename t>
void Tree<t>::readFromFile(string filename)
{
    string str;
    ifstream fileToOpen(filename.c_str());
    if (fileToOpen.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(fileToOpen,str))
        {
            unsigned int pos= 0;
            string token;
            //transform(str.begin(),str.end(),str.begin(),::tolower);
            while (pos = find_if(str.begin(),str.end(),aZCheck)!=str.end()!=string::npos)
            {
                token = str.substr(0, pos);
                transform(token.begin(),token.end(),token.begin(),::tolower);
                Node<t>* ptr=search(token,root);
                if (ptr!=NULL)
                {
                    ptr->count++;
                   // cout<<token<<" already in tree.Count "<<ptr->count<<"\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    insert(token,root);
                    cout<<token<<" added to tree.\n";
                }
                ptr=NULL;
                str.erase(0, pos);
            }

        }
        fileToOpen.close();

    }
    else
        cout<<"Unable to open file!\n";
}

template<typename t>
inline bool Tree<t>::aZCheck(char c)
{
    return !isalpha(c);

}
```

But issue still persists, string is getting split into single characters instead of words, and is whitespace considered valid by isalpha?

Comment: I never used it but  how did `find_first_not_of()` work ? Should just store the pointers as split positions. Include both the upper case and lower case chars in the string passed to the function.

Comment: supposedly returns location of character in a string that is not one of characters indicated, but in my case it just splits into single characters

Comment: You should check for `while( (pos=...) != npos )`

Comment: yep, already added that, without it doesnt split, with it it splits into single characters. Something like this could be done with single 3 word statement in Java .... C++ doesnt make it easy

Comment: Ahh, like I said I never used it, do a lot of C++ too. But if I were going to beat the C++ consortium (or Ms) over the head, I would try single, simple use cases first. Breakpoint on what `pos` returns/

Comment: Oh, you also have to advance the starting search position each pass through the while loop. `_Off Index of the position at which the search is to begin.` Try to not use the erase, just maintain positions. basic_string is troubling.

Comment: I'm going to try your sample as a test case in my compiler, will post what I find.. good luck!

Comment: got it to work... all I needed was +1 on str.erase(0, pos); to include delimiter position as well

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, there is also that `npos` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
...

template<typename t>
void Tree<t>::readFromFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream fileToOpen(filename.c_str());
    if (fileToOpen.is_open())
    {
        for (std::string::iterator pos, prev; std::getline(fileToOpen, str); )
        {                
            for (pos = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isalpha); pos != str.end();
                pos = std::find_if(prev, str.end(), isalpha))
            {
                prev = std::find_if_not(pos, str.end(), isalpha);
                std::string token(pos, prev);
                std::transform(token.begin(), token.end(), token.begin(), ::tolower);
                Node<t>* ptr = search(token, root);
                if (ptr != NULL)
                {
                    ptr->count++;
                   // cout<< token << " already in tree.Count "<<ptr->count<<"\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    insert(token, root);
                    cout << token << " added to tree.\n";
                }
            }
        }
        fileToOpen.close();

    }
    else
        cout<<"Unable to open file!\n";
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/z8jI73)

Also since you say you want to save time, it would benefit you if your insert function does something extra. i.e. insert the value if it is not found in the tree, and set the counter at the position to 1. If the value is in the tree, simply increment the counter. This will save you from doing 2 iterations seeing as your tree might be potentially unbalanced

Comment: Thats exactly what am I doing, my insert function sets count to 1. And I am calling search function just once which returns pointer to node using that pointer I will either increase c ount by one, or add new node if pointer is null

Comment: Your solution is working , but last word wont be counted if there is no delimiter at the end of line, remove last any dot at the end of the line to see what I mean. Same goes if there is only single word on a line, it will be ignored.

Comment: Ok I think it should be fixed now

Comment: So I ran completion times on both solutions, and this one is about 0.003s or 30~ milliseconds faster. When processing file of 570k characters and total time is around 340-345~ ms, or 370~ for @sln solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this test case. Two problems.

1 - Pos is 0 when a delimiter is found at the string start after truncation (or start)
This causes it to break out of the while. Use `npos` as a conditional check instead.

2 - You have to advance the postion past the delimiter when you erase, otherwise
it finds the same one over and over.

```
    int pos= 0;
    string token;
    string str = "Thisis(asdfasdfasdf)and!this)))";

    while ((pos=str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"))!= string::npos )
    {
        if ( pos != 0 )
        {
            // Found a token
            token = str.substr(0, pos);
            cout << "Found: " << token << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // Found another delimiter
            // Just move on to next one
        }

        str.erase(0, pos+1);  // Always remove pos+1 to get rid of delimiter
    }
    // Cover the last (or only) token
    if ( str.length() > 0 )
    {
        token = str;
        cout << "Found: " << token << endl;
    }
```

Outputs >>

```
Found: Thisis
Found: asdfasdfasdf
Found: and
Found: this
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Hey, instant split() !!

Comment: what is int  k used for ?

Comment: I think using [find_if_not](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if_not/) with [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) as a predicate will make this faster and eliminate the need to write out the entire alphabet

Comment: @Smac89 Any chance you could show how to use it, find_if returns an interator instead of position in string,

Comment: @Smac89  - Yeah, this should be faster since `isalpha()` is going to do simple code range conditional check, like `if (c > 'a' && c < 'z' ...)` instead if find_if_not which will check against every character element. @AistisTaraskevicius - I would  try this, iterators are just const char pointers. I'd redesign it around that if you care about speed.

Comment: Well I have nearly 8k unique words ( that repeat up to 4k times). So yes I care about time, I am probably loosing some time because my binary tree isnt self balancing, something I am not looking forward to..